# Hot weather as a trigger for sleep attacks

Tags: sleep, sleep-deprivation, body-temperature, sleep-apnea, weather

According to [this article](https://narcolepsy.sleep-disorders.net/living/most-surprising-symptoms), hot weather can be a trigger for excessive daytime sleepiness in the case of narcolepsy.

I have been trying to find more about a correlation between hot weather and excessive daytime sleepiness (regardless of the specific underlying sleep disorder). My best matches are:

- [Is There a Connection Between Body Temperature and Narcolepsy?](https://narcolepsy.sleep-disorders.net/living/body-temperature)
- [Sleep deprivation disrupts regulation of body heat - Sleep Education](https://sleepeducation.org/sleep-deprivation-disrupts-regulation-body-heat)

Do you have references about such correlation, including anecdotal evidence?